# Anyone has a copy of osxcrypt source code?

Tags: macos, virtual, max, disk

I'd like to get a copy of the following open source code:

http://www.osxcrypt.org/release/OSXCrypt-6.2A-source.zip

The above site is gone, couldn't find any archives googling. So I come here to ask your help. I need some source code to do a virtual disk kernel extension on Mac, so Mac OS X can boot from a virtual disk file, as what we have done for Windows via our VBoot (http://www.vmlite.com/index.php/products/vboot) software.

If you do have a copy and can share with me, that would be great!

Or if you have other ideas on how to develop a virtual disk driver on Mac, that would be useful too. We have done that for Windows/Linux.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't believe this is a programming question. This may not be the right place for it.

Answer (score 1):

Executable download: http://www.apponic.com/free-downloads-327/osxcrypt-6.2a/

As for the source, a [Google search constrained to the past year](http://www.google.co.za/search?tbs=qdr%3ay&q=OSXCrypt-6.2A-source.zip) reveals nothing at all. The last post [here](http://forum.pgp.com/t5/PGP-Whole-Disk-Encryption-for/Partition-level-encryption-in-Mac-PGP-10-x/td-p/38606) isn't promising:

> In 2008 some fellows took the
>   Truecrypt source code and wrote their
>   own Mac version (this was before there
>   was a Mac version of Truecrypt).  It
>   was called OSXCrypt.  It had potential
>   because it was a kernel extension, not
>   a user-space implementation like
>   Truecrypt is.  They asked for and took
>   donations, but once Truecrypt was
>   released for Mac, these guys took the
>   money and ran.  No one to my knowledge
>   has heard from them since.  Pity.

Comment: that's only the binary, not the source

Comment: thanks, that's really weird. Their sf.net project has no source code neither.

Answer (score 1):

Google search 'osxcrypt' gives numerous sites from which the binary can be downloaded.  However, they all seem to lead to dead-ends - the `osxcrypt.org` domain is defunct (which is probably indicative of problems with the software; I'd certainly not recommend using it at the moment).  Using the WayBack Machine at http://web.archive.org suggests that the website was always rather minimal - there's no evidence of the source being available there for the 2 one-page entries that are available.  There were plans to put the material onto SourceForge; the project exists but there are no files available there.

There's a contact email address available via `whois osxcrypt.org` - maybe you should try that.

Comment: already sent an email to the owner of that domain, no responses yet. Seems there is zero source code as to start a hello world virtual disk driver on Mac. All points to MacFuse and osxcrypt. MacFuse is a user space, which we can't use.

Answer (score 0):

After searching in the waybackmachine it was authored by [Orlando Bassotto](https://it.linkedin.com/in/orlando-bassotto-24b14533) and [Matteo Flora](https://matteoflora.com/).

Maybe someone can ping them.